# Python importação de módulos erro

Tags: python, importação

Estou com problemas na importação dos módulos no meu projeto. Estava criando alguns testes e não consigo importar a main do meu projeto para testar um end point, a partir do meu arquivo de testes `teste_ex.py`. Segue a estrutura do projeto:

```
backend_api/
    api/
        __init__.py
        main.py
    testes/
        __init__.py
        test_ex.py
```

Então no meu test_ex.py estou tentando importar a `main` da seguinte forma:

```
import api.main
from webtest import TestApp

def test_functional_concursos_api():
    app = TestApp(main.app)
    assert app.get('/hello').status == '200 OK'
```

Apenas recebo `ImportError: No module named 'api'`

Answer (score 2):

Não aconselho importares módulos pertencentes a uma pasta "pai".

Dito isto, se não existe outra solução, o meu conselho é criares um pacotes com o teu módulo e fazeres uma [importação relativa](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports).

Depois podes efetuar a importação desta forma:

```
from .api import main
```

Mas só depois de criares o módulo.

O `.` antes do nome da "pasta" ou módulo se refere a uma pasta pai. Pode-se utilizar mais de um para subir níveis mais acima.

Comment: Isso seria criando um unit e importando nele?

Comment: Se com "unit" te referes a "um módulo não instalado" creio que sim.